# Mi consulta MySQL no funciona cuando uso un %

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT calldate, src, dst 
FROM cdr 
WHERE src != '442%' AND src != '044%' LIMIT 50;
```

Si lo corre, pero no sé si en realidad está bien hecho.

Lo que necesito hacer es traer los datos marcados donde la condición es que el **src sea diferente de 442 (aquí tiene mas números por eso le puse el símbolo %) y así con 004.**

Comment: Edita el título de tu pregunta, no es llamativo ni conciso, también ayudaría que mostraras los resultados que te devuelve y los resultados esperados.

Comment: esta bien para buscar registros que sean el campo src sean diferente a '442%' y '044%' pero si los campos son iguales a '442' y'044' esta consulta no te va a funcionar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa `not like` para comparar en negativo strings con consultas tipo like.

```
SELECT calldate, src, dst 
FROM cdr 
WHERE src NOT LIKE '442%' AND src NOT LIKE '044%' LIMIT 50;
```

Puedes ver más info [aquí](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-like.php).

Comment: Hola, tal vez quieras explicarle la razón por la cual usas un `NOT LIKE` y la razón por la cual su consulta no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Tu intención de búsqueda es correcta. El problema es que el *wildcard* `%` solo funciona como lo quieres usar cuando se usa un `LIKE`. Cuando lo usas en tu consulta:

```
SELECT calldate, src, dst 
FROM cdr 
WHERE src != '442%' AND src != '044%' LIMIT 50;
```

Estás buscando literalmente aquellas diferentes a a `442%` y `044%`, por lo tanto obtendrás resultados como `4420000` porque `442%` es diferente a `4420000`. Es decir, se está considerando el símbolo `%` de forma literal.

Lo que necesitas (como bien menciona @Carmen) es usar un `LIKE`. Con `LIKE` puedes usar `%` para representar cualquier cantidad de caracteres por lo que en este caso usar un `LIKE '442%'`, por ejemplo, obtendría todos aquellos que empiecen con `442`: `442`, `442000`, `442001`, etc.

Pero tu necesitas la inversa, por eso lo que tienes que hacer es usar un `NOT` en tu query:

```
SELECT calldate, src, dst 
FROM cdr 
WHERE src NOT LIKE '442%' AND src NOT LIKE '044%' LIMIT 50;
```

Que quiere decir que vas a obtener todos aquellos registros en los cuales `src` no empiece ni con `442` ni con `044`.